# String difference in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have an input string $foo which contains both alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters.

I use ereg_replace to $foo to replace all non-wanted chars with empty chars. Now I want to know what were these "erased" chars. How can I do this?

Comment: Please add your code to your question so that an answer may include the modification that you request.

Comment: The `ereg*` family of functions is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. Consider using the `preg*` family of functions instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using regex to replace, why don't you just use the same regex and do a "preg_match", then a "preg_replace"

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
$foo = "something";
$bar = ereg_replace(...);
array_diff(chunk_split($foo, 1), chunk_split($bar, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 5.3:

```
$text = 'Hello, World!';
$stripped = '';
$text = preg_replace_callback('/([^A-Za-z0-9]+)/',
   function($m) use (&$stripped) { $stripped .= $m[0]; return ''; }, $text);

echo "$text\n$stripped\n";
```

Output:

```
HelloWorld
, !
```